# What's wrong with code designed to check type

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the function with regexp, that should detect the type: Undefined | Null of the applied object:

```
var isUndefinedOrNull = function(obj) {
    return /^(?:undefined|null)$/.test(typeof obj);
};
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: can you give a case where it is failing

Comment: `typeof null` is `object`

Answer (score 3):

The only problem is `typeof` [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) is `object` not `'null'`.

I think you can use

```
var isUndefinedOrNull = function (obj) {
    return obj === undefined || obj === null;
};
```

- [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)
- [Datastructures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: `/^(?:undefined|null)$/.test(typeof obj);` returns true for me.

Comment: Arun P Johny, but if we pass var test = null;
console.debug(isUndefinedOrNull(test)); - it will be false: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/intavi/q6dzxokt/1/

Comment: @designeng can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8y5fs2uf/1/) to create any failure case that you have

Comment: @designeng `null === null` is true, so the test should be fine